# Не работает Emmet в Jade синтаксисе (Sublime Text 3)

Tags: sublime-text, jade, emmet

При работе в Sublime Text 3 с файлом `index.jade` (также попробовал `index.haml`) не работает плагин *Emmet*.

Подскажите, почему не работает?

В файлах `html`, `css`, `sass` *Emmet* работает.

Comment: [Возможное разрешение проблемы](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/issues/406#issuecomment-151144075).

Comment: Попробуйте удалить Emmet и установить заново